# why the number of reducers is greater than what I specified in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Here is the output on console of my MR job. The job successfully completed. But I have two concerns.

1) I specified `-D mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.75`. however the reducer did not start when is map is 75% done as seen below

2) I specified `-D mapred.reduce.tasks=2`. But the number of launched reducer tasks is 3 (as seen below).

why these two parameters are have not been taken care of?

```
hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount -D mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.75 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 /data /output/result1
2014-07-06 22:25:11.733 java[3236:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
14/07/06 22:25:13 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
14/07/06 22:25:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/07/06 22:25:13 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/07/06 22:25:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201407061919_0015
14/07/06 22:25:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/07/06 22:25:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 25% reduce 0%
14/07/06 22:25:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/07/06 22:26:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 75% reduce 0%
14/07/06 22:26:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/07/06 22:26:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 8%
14/07/06 22:26:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
14/07/06 22:26:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 37%
14/07/06 22:26:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 54%
14/07/06 22:26:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 66%
14/07/06 22:26:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 86%
14/07/06 22:26:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201407061919_0015
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 29
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=3
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=107522
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=51153
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=880862
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=2217446
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=3672001
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=4030974
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=880862
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=3671571
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=1474437
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=77934
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=1474437
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=255974
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=6076197
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=589447168
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=19030
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=629184
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=430
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=102328
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=82339
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=102328
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=888221696
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=82339
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=6509461504
14/07/06 22:26:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=629184
```

EDIT: without any parameters on command line:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount /data/ /output/results2
2014-07-06 20:05:29.428 java[2869:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
14/07/06 20:05:29 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
14/07/06 20:05:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/07/06 20:05:29 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/07/06 20:05:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201407061919_0009
14/07/06 20:05:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/07/06 20:05:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 25% reduce 0%
14/07/06 20:05:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/07/06 20:05:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/07/06 20:05:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
14/07/06 20:05:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201407061919_0009
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 29
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=53468
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=14440
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=880862
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=2214915
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=3672001
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=3974001
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=880862
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=3671571
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=1474413
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=77934
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=1474413
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=255974
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=6076197
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=557662208
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=10370
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=629184
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=430
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=102328
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=82339
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=102328
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=802287616
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=82339
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=5418221568
14/07/06 20:06:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=629184
```

Comment: Make sure you are either spelling it -Dproperty=value (with no spaces) or -Dproperty value (with one space) or else it might be parsed wrong

Comment: @rVr: without specifying I see that my reducer is 1. so setting the value, indeed changes it

Comment: looks like you are also using a combiner which may or may not be called by framework? Can you paste full printout with and without setting mapred.reduce.tasks=2?

Comment: @rVr: I have updated above

Comment: One thing for sure is that reducer progress in job output does not include shuffle phase. The reduce phase has 3 steps: shuffle, sort, reduce. Shuffle is where the data is collected by the reducer from each mapper. What you are asking by specifying mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.75 is for reducers to start shuffling data when 75% of map task is done. It still does not start sort and reduce phase of reducer (which start only after 100% of map tasks are done), that would be my understanding for your question 1

Comment: What mode are you running hadoop in? Can you check Job tracker GUI interface to confirm how many reduce tasks did job use?

Comment: @rVr: I thought the same way. but sort stage is done before shuffle. That is the data is sorted/partitioned and finally shuffled across network to different data nodes. Sort step is more of merge phase. when a mapper produces intermediate key,value pairs, before it is persisted on disk, it is partitioned (sorted) for reducers. (This is my understanding from hadoop: the definitive guide book)

Comment: @rVr: but why the number of reducers is 3 instead of 2??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I specified -D mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.75. however the reducer did not start when is map is 75% done as seen below

75% of map progress does not necessarily mean that 75% of the map tasks have finished. What this command means is that when 75% (3 map tasks out of 4 in your case) of the map tasks are **completed**, the reducers will start the shuffling phase. See [this post](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/) for more details on how progress is defined.

> 2) I specified -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2. But the number of launched reducer tasks is 3 (as seen below).

The same reduce task may be launched on several nodes (that's called "[speculative execution](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#tolerence)"). When one of the nodes finishes it first, the other node gets a "kill" signal for this task.

Another possibility is that one of the reduce tasks fails in one node and gets executed successfully in another.